# intercepting url rewrite module, prevent rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

Is there anything that would cause the url rewrite module in IIS to not fire off? Maybe a site that is in integrated mode or an http handler?

I have tried a few different things to get the rewrite rules to work but nothing. My latest is as such

```
<rewrite>
      <rewriteMaps>

      </rewriteMaps>
      <rules>
        <rule name="rewriterule" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />

          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.google.com" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

and it doesn't work at all. I've tried various regex, etc. Its like it doesnt get used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in my case is that you have to be running the site in the same target platform as the url rewrite module. for example, I have x64 version of url rewrite module installed but the site was running under 32bit. Once I setup the site to run under 64bit, the rewrite started working.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have your answer but here are some other possible things that might cause Rewrite Module not to work :

- When you deploy your web site and see this feature not working on
  your server, it is highly possible that you misconfigured something
  on your server. One of the misconfiguration you might have done could
  be setting the **overrideModeDefault** attribute to Deny for rules under
  `<sectionGroup name="rewrite">` inside your applicationHost.config
  file.
- If you are on a **shared hosting environment** and you see this feature
  not working, then ask your provider if they have given you the
  permission of configuring this part.
- In your development environment, if you run your web site under
  **Visual Studio Development Sever**, you won’t be able to see this
  feature working. You need to configure your application to run under
  at least **IIS Express** to see this feature working.